# Is it correct to put a definition in parentheses?

Tags: meaning, punctuation, writing-style, parentheses, parentheticals

Here is an example:

> The process includes situation awareness (the state of knowing the conditions that affect one’s work)...

I want to know whether it is correct (or acceptable or unacceptable) to put the definition in parentheses.

Comment: I wouldn't have said that grammar comes into it.  It seems perfectly acceptable, although you might want to prefix it with *namely* or *that is* in tha manner: "... awareness (namely, the state of ...)" to make it clear you're explaining the the preceding term.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, most of English grammar is subjective. The choice to put a definition in parenthesis is perfectly valid - at most it is a stylistic choice. Despite this, it is generally more widely accepted to offset a definition using an appositive phrase than to awkwardly integrate it into a sentence using parenthesis.

Comment: Honestly, the rise of the addition of the word "honestly", where it adds nothing to a sentence, is an interesting quirk of 2015-2016.

Answer (score 0):

One piece of style guide advice that directly addresses your question appears in *The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **6.99** *Glosses or translations.* Parentheses are used to enclose glosses of unfamiliar terms or translations of foreign terms—or, if the term is given in English, to enclose the original word. ...
>
> > [Relevant example:] A drop folio (a page number printed at the foot of a page) is useful on the opening page of a chapter.

In the example, the "gloss" provided in parentheses for the term *drop folio* is essentially equivalent to definition, as you use the term in your question.

*The Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) offers similar advice, though with not-as-on-point examples:

> **5.11.1 Parentheses** ... Use parentheses for digressions, explanations, glosses, and translations:
>
> > [Most relevant example:] the 25th Foot (afterwards named the King's Own Scottish Borderers)

So it appears that as long as you characterize your definition as a "gloss," you can find support from style guides for putting it in parentheses immediately following the term you want to define.

On a wider view, the answer to your question is something like this: It is clearly not incorrect to put definitions (or glosses) in parentheses immediately after introducing the term in question, unless you are obliged to follow a specific style guide that requires you to follow specific rules for handling definitions that forbid such treatment. If you are not bound to a particular style guide, you can make your own decision about how to present in-text definitions; and certainly *Chicago* and *Oxford* seem inclined to endorse the use of parentheses for that purpose.